# How can the odbl / dbcl data be used?

Tags: united-kingdom, licensing

We have a database containing a list of addresses and want to start performing some analysis based on those addresses.

It feels important to note we aren't selling or making our service public (or its results), it is for internal use within the company only.

Having done some investigation into the different geocoding services a lot of them say "dont store the results" which is a no go in this case as we have too many to geocode every request.

This lead me to discover you can self host [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) a service that can be used geocode addresses. My understanding of Nominatim is that the database and the data in the database are covered by two similar licenses. ([odbl](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/) and [dbcl](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/dbcl/1-0/))

Given that we want to take our addresses, geocode them & store the lat/long pairs back to our own database I'm concerned we are creating a derivative database that has to be published.

So would we be creating a derivative database that has to be published? Or is the fact the intended use case is not for "public consumption" enough to cover us from such an situation?

Other things that may be important

- Based in the UK.
- We have no intention of modifying the underlying Nominatim database or adding data to it, just extracting & storing lat/long pairs for our own analysis later.
- We won't use our own API for geocoding, just for searching the lat/long pairs
- I have read [openstreetmap Legal FAQ](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Open_Data_License/Trivial_Transformations_-_Guideline) about data transformations but it still feels somewhat unclear to me
- I have also read [openstreetmap Use Cases](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/License/Use_Cases) page, while it does explicitly say the following I am still uncomfortable for some reason!

> Case 1: I want to use OSM data in a purely internal application
>
> ODbL only places restrictions on "public" use. If you are a company, and the map or app will only be visible to/usable by employees, this is allowed and you don't have to do anything.